# Disable parallel execution in TestNG - version 6.14

Tags: testng

For me each class contains only one test. Each class depends on its previous class for some data. So i need the execution to be sequential with the same order i mention in testng.xml. But despite trying all the possible ways, classes are getting executed in parallel.

i tried parallel as "none", "false".  Below is the format of my testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SanitySuite">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="XYZScripts.Listeners" />
    </listeners>

    <parameter name="BROWSER" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="URL" value="http://blabla.com" />

    <test name="XYZTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="XYZ.Class1" />
            <class name="XYZ.Class2" />
            <class name="XYZ.Class3" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: How are you stating that tests are still running in parallel? Does any of your test classes use a data provider ? Please edit your question and add details around these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce your thread count to one. This is how [TestNG test runner](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestRunner.java) decides how many threads to generate for your test suite:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SanitySuite">

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="XYZScripts.Listeners" />
</listeners>

<parameter name="BROWSER" value="chrome" />
<parameter name="URL" value="http://blabla.com" />

<test name="XYZTests" parallel="classes" thread-count="1">
    <classes>
        <class name="XYZ.Class1" />
        <class name="XYZ.Class2" />
        <class name="XYZ.Class3" />
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a mistake from my side. I had @BeforeTest and @AfterTest annotations in the classes, hence those methods are getting executed in parallel. I replaced them with @BeforeClass and @AfterClass to resolve. Thanks all.